# datatype exception in simple GAE form using datastore

Tags: python, forms, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am an absolutely newb to GAE and am trying my first sample application.
I have written a simple HTMl form. on clicking submit, the details in the fields need to be saved in the datastore.

My problem is that I am getting datatype exceptions and i have no idea where i am going wrong

```
import cgi
import datetime
import urllib
import wsgiref.handlers
import os
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class Champion(db.Model):
    champion_first_name = db.StringProperty()
    champion_last_name = db.StringProperty()
    champion_email = db.EmailProperty()
    champion_phone_code = db.IntegerProperty()
    champion_phone_number = db.IntegerProperty()
    diabetic_first_name = db.StringProperty()
    diabetic_last_name = db.StringProperty()
    diabetic_age = db.IntegerProperty()
    diabetic_gender = db.StringProperty()
    diabetic_email = db.EmailProperty()
    diabetic_phone_code = db.IntegerProperty()
    diabetic_phone_number = db.IntegerProperty()
    diabetic_city = db.StringProperty()
    diabetic_zipcode = db.IntegerProperty()
    diabetic_since = db.IntegerProperty()
    diabetic_relationship = db.StringProperty()
    checkup_date = db.DateProperty ()
    md_advert_feedback = db.StringProperty()
    timestamp = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template_values = {}
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'main.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))

    def post(self):
        pledge_data = Champion(champion_first_name = cgi.escape(self.request.get('champ_first_name')),
                    champion_last_name = cgi.escape(self.request.get('champ_last_name')),
                    champion_email = cgi.escape(self.request.get('champ_email')),
                    champion_phone_code = cgi.escape(self.request.get('champ_phone_code')),
                    champion_phone_number = cgi.escape(self.request.get('champ_phone_number')),
                    diabetic_first_name = cgi.escape(self.request.get('diab_first_name')),
                    diabetic_last_name = cgi.escape(self.request.get('diab_last_name')),
                    diabetic_age = cgi.escape(self.request.get('diab_age')),
                    diabetic_gender = cgi.escape(self.request.get('diab_gender')),
                    diabetic_email = cgi.escape(self.request.get('diab_email')),
                    diabetic_phone_code = cgi.escape(self.request.get('diab_phone_code')),
                    diabetic_phone_number = cgi.escape(self.request.get('diab_phone_number')),
                    diabetic_city = cgi.escape(self.request.get('diab_city')),
                    diabetic_zipcode = cgi.escape(self.request.get('diab_zip')))
                    # diabetic_since = cgi.escape(int(self.request.get('diab_since'))))
                    # diabetic_relationship = cgi.escape(self.request.get('diab_relationship')),
                    # md_advert_feedback = cgi.escape(self.request.get('md_ad_feedback'))
                    # checkup_date = cgi.escape(self.request.get('checkup_date')),
                    # )

        pledge_data.put()


application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)


def main():
  run_wsgi_app(application)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

The error i am getting is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\_webapp25.py", line 703, in __call__
    handler.post(*groups)
  File "C:\Users\Rishav\Documents\Google App Engine\helloworld\main.py", line 54, in post
    diabetic_zipcode = cgi.escape(self.request.get('diab_zip')))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\db\__init__.py", line 945, in __init__
    prop.__set__(self, value)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\db\__init__.py", line 599, in __set__
    value = self.validate(value)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\db\__init__.py", line 3141, in validate
    % (self.name, type(value).__name__))
BadValueError: Property champion_phone_number must be an int or long, not a unicode
```

I am absolutely certain the answer is gonna make me faceplam, but i am just not getting it now. I believe I have put in the correct db model.
also, it makes no difference if I actually input any data in the webform form field or not. I get the same error even when i leave the fields null and then hit submit.

EDIT:
OP here.
in case anyone is interested in what i did;
once I converted all required field data to int, i found another error.
I would get valueerror eception if any of my fields had null value.
Now i want to leave all my data entry validation on the client side. 
so i changed my code to;

```
def post(self):
    pledge_data = Champion()
    try:
        pledge_data.champion_first_name = cgi.escape(self.request.get('champ_first_name'))
        pledge_data.champion_last_name = cgi.escape(self.request.get('champ_last_name'))
        pledge_data.champion_email = cgi.escape(self.request.get('champ_email'))
        pledge_data.champion_phone_code = int(cgi.escape(self.request.get('champ_phone_code')))
        pledge_data.champion_phone_number = int(cgi.escape(self.request.get('champ_phone_number')))
        pledge_data.diabetic_first_name = cgi.escape(self.request.get('diab_first_name'))
        pledge_data.diabetic_last_name = cgi.escape(self.request.get('diab_last_name'))
        pledge_data.diabetic_age = int(cgi.escape(self.request.get('diab_age')))
        pledge_data.diabetic_gender = cgi.escape(self.request.get('diab_gender'))
        pledge_data.diabetic_email = cgi.escape(self.request.get('diab_email'))
        pledge_data.diabetic_phone_code = int(cgi.escape(self.request.get('diab_phone_code')))
        pledge_data.diabetic_phone_number = int(cgi.escape(self.request.get('diab_phone_number')))
        pledge_data.diabetic_city = cgi.escape(self.request.get('diab_city'))
        pledge_data.diabetic_zipcode = int(cgi.escape(self.request.get('diab_zip')))
        pledge_data.diabetic_since = int(cgi.escape(self.request.get('diab_since')))
                # diabetic_relationship = cgi.escape(self.request.get('diab_relationship')),
                # md_advert_feedback = cgi.escape(self.request.get('md_ad_feedback'))
                # checkup_date = cgi.escape(self.request.get('checkup_date')),
                # )
    except ValueError:
        pass

    pledge_data.put()
```

Comment: +1 for including a relevant code sample and full traceback. Thank you.

Comment: and thank you for adding in the python tag. forgot that. :D

Comment: no worries. it wasn't necessary until they added Go and Java support :D

Comment: Why would you want to store a phone number as an integer? This seems like a Very Bad Idea(tm).

Comment: Phone numbers aren't integers - trying to store them that way is a bad idea. Likewise, you should do escaping on output, not on input (as in your last code snippet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick fix is to explicitly cast, e.g.:

```
...
champion_phone_number = int(cgi.escape(self.request.get('champ_phone_number'))),
...
```

Comment: If you see one of my commented lines contains;

         
        # diabetic_since = cgi.escape(int(self.request.get('diab_since'))))

it was what i tried the very first time i got the error. i have used int inside the cgi.escape clause. -_- /facepalm.

Comment: And that's OK! You are not your code. We all do stuff like that. Get out there and get that next bug! My guess: it's going to be a much more difficult one to solve.

Answer (score 1):

all request arguments are strings. if you need the property is of another type like champion_phone_number you need to explicitly transform it into an int()